# How to enable java 7 on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, installation

Hello everyone I'm looking for method to change my default java for macbook air. I'm new user in mac and I dont know how and where to do it. I've installed Java 7 from Oracle website but when I want to run eclipse it shows alert that I need java 7 version.

Comment: Could it be that it says you need the _JDK_?

Comment: That's what I have. http://pl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=978bhg&s=8

Comment: That looks like Eclipse Luna, which is probably worth mentioning (although I think Kepler has a similar requirement).

Comment: What do you mean? How can I install and run this eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you've set your JAVA_HOME environment variable: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html

This means put the following in your ~/.environment file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-dir
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`
```

Comment: where I can find jdk installation dir?

Comment: It's whereever you installed it to.

Comment: But it installed automatically I just click twice on icon I didn't choose dir.

Comment: check /usr/lib/java/

Comment: I didn't have JDK thanks man :)